# Entity Frameworok generate guid as id and save it

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, api

I'm trying to save to my table Users let's say, string ID, string email, and string password. The problem is that ID must be a guid that I have to create it and save it and not SQL server. Any ideas how?

I searched but I only found how to make SQL server to create the guid.

Comment: if you don't want assign the `generate guid` to database, you can use `Guid.NewGuid()` function to generate guid, then save

Comment: The problem is that i'm getting the full object from a request, so I just have to save it and not generate it. I put the DatabaseGeneratedOption.None before int ID and im using postman to save lets say ID=12321 (integer for now) Email = email Password=pass and it replaces the id with the default one

Comment: so, you use Entity Framework for ORM? I think you should checkout the value of `ID` field on database with ID property of model in Entity Framework.

Comment: wrong mapping field usually make it be reset to default value

Comment: I also tried DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity but i cant add the id i want to database for some reason

Comment: DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity => it just a attribute of EntityFramework. just forgot it. what is your type of field ID in your database: INT, VARCHAR  or anything else

Answer (score 0):

First of all, tell Entity framework that you will generate the value of the primary key:
Use [DatabaseGenerated Attribute](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute)

```
public class School
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

The None option prevents values from being generated by the database automatically in cases where they would otherwise be created.

Furthermore, consider to overwrite DbContext.SaveChanges(). In this procedure ask the ChangeTracker for all elements that are Added. Generate an Id for every Added element. It might be dangerous to let others generate an Id, because they might be adding a constant value or just an auto-increment.

Another possibility would be to generate it within the Add function, but if you do that, then users could change your generated Id. So the proper place is within SaveChanges:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var addedElements = this.ChangeTracker.Entries
        .Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Added);

    foreach(var addedElement in addedElements)
    {
        // This will fail: the added element doesn't have a property Id:
        addedElement.Id = GenerateId();
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

For this you have to be certain that every added element has a property Id. The simplest way is to create an interface and let all your tables implement this interface:

```
public interface IID
{
    string Id {get; set;}
}

public class School : IID {...}
public class Student : IID {...}
public class Teacher : IID {...}

public class DbContext
{
    public DbSet<School> Schools {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Student> Students{get; set;}
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
         var addedElements = this.ChangeTracker.Entries.Cast<IID>
        .Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Added);

        foreach(var addedElement in addedElements)
        {
            addedElement.Id = GenerateId(); // Every Added element implements IId
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private string GenerateId()
    {
         ... // TODO: return unique ID, for instance a GUID
    }
}
```